# Opencv2.4.13 and PYTHON2_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I used `ccmake..` GUI to configure the `OpenCV` for compilation.

I like to include Python in Opecv's build process. So `BUILD_opencv_python` is set `ON`.

But there is no option to set `PYTHON2_INCLUDE_PATH` in the ccmake GUI for this Opencv2.4.13 cmake. How can I include that path in compilation?

If not, I have `Python.h not found error`.

I have only `PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR and PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH`  in the GUI.

I use anaconda2 for Python2.7.

`Python.h` exists inside `~/anaconda2/include/python2.7`.
So I copied the file into `include folder inside numpy`, but still have not found error.

Answer (score 0):

for **PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR** , set the path as the following

```
    /path2anaconda/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
```

for **PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH**, set

```
            /path2anaconda/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

it should work after that if there aren't any other errors.